# UL list-style-image not working in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, html-lists

I set a UL style to use a doctor image as the list style image in the Site.Master page. When I run it from visual studio 2010, the image can be seen. However when I published the project and open it with internet explorer and firefox, I can not see the image. I have attached the code below(the doctor image is inside the Content folder). Anyone has any idear how to solve this problem? Thank you, really appreciate for any help.

```
<ul style = "list-style-image: url(/Content/doctor.jpg);">
            <li><a href = "<%= Url.Content("~/Home/Index") %>">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href = "<%= Url.Content("~/Home/Patient") %>">Patient Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href = "<%= Url.Content("~/Home/Invoice") %>">Invoice Entry</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that you're publishing to a folder now at the web site root.

When running the site in the built-in Visual Studio server, the application root is `/`, so `/Content/doctor.jpg` is correct.

When publishing, the root directory may be different, such as http://www.site.com/app, so `/Content/doctor.jpg` points to

`http://www.site.com/Content/doctor.jpg`

When it should point to

`http://www.site.com/app/Content/doctor.jpg`

To correct this, change this:

```
<ul style = "list-style-image: url(/Content/doctor.jpg);">
```

to this:

```
<ul style = "list-style-image: url(<%= Url.Content("~/Content/doctor.jpg") %>);">
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, when you publish your app it's not at the root.  Therefore, /Content is not the right folder.  If you're using a style attribute, then do what you did for the links.  `<%= Url.Content("~/Content/doctor.jpg") %>`  If you put it in a css file, then you have to make sure to use paths relative to the style sheets location.